# Jquery Function Not working after i go into another page?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html

I'm on working to build android apps with phone gap and jQuery. I make one index.html pages to entirely my apps, and I divide my page with sections like this:

```
<!-- PAGE DRIVER -->
        <section class="page" id="homedriver">
            <div class="header home">
               <img class="center" src="images/gamya_icon.png" width="160px" />
                <a href="javascript:;" class="right-menu" onclick="openRightMenu();">
                    <div class="menu-circle"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a href="javascript:;" id="btnPick" class="menu-half" onclick="openPage('m_pick');">
                    <img src="images/pick.png" class="center" width="128px" />
                    <span>Pick Up</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- PAGE DRIVER -->
```

the flow is: when section with id="homedriver" loaded, I call jquery function with interval 2 seconds, and when I clicked Button with id="btnClick" the interval is stopped, and the section with id="m_pick" is opened

```
<!-- Order -->
    <section class="page index7 hidden" id="m_pick">
        <div class="header index7">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="backpage" onclick="backMenu(); resetForm('formSubmitPick'); set_interval_job();">
                <div class="arrow-left"></div>
            </a>
            <div class="title">Pick Up</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content main">
            <form action="javascript:;" method="post" id="formSubmitPick">
                <button type="submit" class="fixed-top-right index7">
                    Submit
                    <div class="chevron-right"></div>
                </button>
                <div class="field-name">Customer Name</div>
                <div class="input-group-full">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Type Your Location" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-name">From</div>
                <div class="input-group-full">
                    <input type="text" name="location_from" id="location_from" placeholder="Type Your Location" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-name">To</div>
                <div class="input-group-full">
                    <input type="text" name="location_to" id="location_to" placeholder="Type Your Destination" autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Order -->
```

That was I exactly want.

Now the problem is, when I back into section with id="homedriver" then I click the button with id="btnClick" the interval still running?
Please help me.

here my javascript code
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $( "#btnPick" ).on( "click",function() {
        clear_interval_job();
      });

```
 $('#login_form').validate({
    rules : {
        login_user : {'required' : true},
        login_pass : {'required' : true}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('#login_form input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
        $.ajax({
            url         : server + 'login',
            data        : $(form).serialize(),
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            async       : false,
            cache       : false,
            success     : function(response){
                if(response.status == 'ok'){
                        if(response.group == 8){
                            window.localStorage.setItem("id", response.id);
                            session = response.id;
                            $('.page#login').addClass('animate-0').addClass('zoomOut');
                            $('.page#home').addClass('animate-0').addClass('zoomOut');
                            $('.page#homedriver').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                                        var id_driver = localStorage.getItem("id");
                                        interval_job  = setInterval(function() {
                                         $.ajax({
                                                    url         : server + 'order/check_order/'+id_driver,
                                                    type        : 'POST',
                                                    dataType    : 'json',
                                                    async       : false,
                                                    cache       : false,
                                                    success     : function(response){
                                                        if(response.order_num >= 1){
                                                             window.localStorage.setItem('id_order',response.order_detail.id);
                                                             openAlertDriver(response.order_detail.name,response.order_detail.mylocation,response.order_detail.destination);
                                                             clear_interval_job(interval);

                                                        }else if(response.order_num == 0){

                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    error       : function(){
                                                        openAlert('No Connection','exitApp');

                                                    },
                                                    timeout     : 6000
                                                });
                                }, 2000);   
                            });
                            setTimeout( function(){
                                $('.page#login').removeClass('animate-0').removeClass('zoomOut').hide();
                                $('.page#home').removeClass('animate-0').removeClass('zoomOut').hide();
                            }, 500);
                        }else if(response.group == 1){
                             window.localStorage.setItem("id", response.id);
                            session = response.id;
                            $('.page#login').addClass('animate-0').addClass('zoomOut');
                            $('.page#homedriver').addClass('animate-0').addClass('zoomOut');
                            $('.page#home').fadeIn();
                            setTimeout( function(){
                                $('.page#login').removeClass('animate-0').removeClass('zoomOut').hide();
                                $('.page#homedriver').removeClass('animate-0').removeClass('zoomOut').hide();
                            }, 500);
                        }
                }else{
                    $(form).addClass('animate0').addClass('wobble');
                    $('.users').addClass('error');
                    $('.password').addClass('error');
                    setTimeout( function(){
                        $(form).removeClass('animate0').removeClass('wobble');
                    }, 1000);
                    hideLoading();
                }
            }

        });
    }
});

$('#formSubmitOrder').validate({
    rules : {
        location_from : {'required' : true},
        name          : {'required' : true}

    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('#formSubmitOrder input[type="submit"]').val('PLEASE WAIT').attr('disabled',true);
        var id_user = localStorage.getItem("id");
        $.ajax({
            url         : server + 'order/save_order/' + id_user,
            data        : $(form).serialize(),
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            async       : false,
            cache       : false,
            success     : function(response){
                if(response.status == 'ok'){
                     window.localStorage.setItem("id_order", response.id_order);
                    $('#formSubmitOrder input[type="submit"]').val('SEND').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#formSubmitOrder').trigger('reset');
                    $('.page#m_order').fadeOut();
                    $('.page#m_wait_respon').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                            var timesRun = 0;
                            interval = setInterval(function() {
                                timesRun += 1;
                                var id_order = localStorage.getItem("id_order");
                                 $.ajax({
                                            url         : server + 'order/get_respon/'+ id_order,
                                            type        : 'POST',
                                            dataType    : 'json',
                                            async       : false,
                                            cache       : false,
                                            success     : function(response){
                                                if(response.status == 1 && timesRun <= 20){
                                                     clearInterval(interval);
                                                     $('.page#m_respon').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                                                            $.ajax({
                                                            url         : server + 'order/get_driver_info/'+id_order,
                                                            type        : 'POST',
                                                            dataType    : 'json',
                                                            async       : false,
                                                            cache       : false,
                                                            success     : function(response){
                                                                $.each(response.info,function(){
                                                                    $('#drivername').val(this.driverName);
                                                                    $('#driverid').val(this.nip);
                                                                    $('#carnumber').val(this.carNumber);
                                                                    $('#platenumber').val(this.nopol);

                                                                });   
                                                            }

                                                        });
                                                     });
                                                }else if(timesRun >= 20){
                                                    openAlert("Order Failed, Please Try Again");
                                                    clearInterval(interval);
                                                    $('.page#m_wait_respon').fadeOut();
                                                    $('.page#m_order').fadeIn();
                                                }
                                            },
                                            error       : function(){
                                                openAlert('No Connection','exitApp');

                                            },
                                            timeout     : 6000
                                        });
                        }, 2000);   
                    });
                }else{
                    openAlert('Failed to send order');
                }
            },
            error       : function(){
                openAlert('No Connection','exitApp');
            },
            timeout     : 6000
        });
    }
});

$('#formSubmitPick').validate({
    rules : {
        location_from : {'required' : true},
        name          : {'required' : true}

    },
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $('#formSubmitPick input[type="submit"]').val('PLEASE WAIT').attr('disabled',true);
        var id_driver = localStorage.getItem("id");
        $.ajax({
            url         : server + 'order/save_pick/' + id_driver,
            data        : $(form).serialize(),
            type        : 'POST',
            dataType    : 'json',
            async       : false,
            cache       : false,
            success     : function(response){
                if(response.status == 'ok'){
                     window.localStorage.setItem("id_order", response.id_order);
                    $('#formSubmitPick input[type="submit"]').val('SEND').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#formSubmitPick').trigger('reset');
                    $('.page#m_pick').fadeOut();
                    $('.page#m_current_job').fadeIn('slow',function(){
                         var  id_driver = localStorage.getItem("id");
                         var id_order   = localStorage.getItem("id_order");
                             $.ajax({
                                        url         : server + 'order/get_order_pick/'+ id_order +'/'+ id_driver,
                                        type        : 'POST',
                                        dataType    : 'json',
                                        async       : false,
                                        cache       : false,
                                        success     : function(response){
                                            $('#customername').val(response.pick_detail.name);
                                            $('#from').val(response.pick_detail.mylocation);
                                            $('#to').val(response.pick_detail.destination);
                                            $('.duty_loader').hide();
                                            $('.arrived_ok').show();
                                            $('#done').show();
                                            clearInterval(interval_job);
                                        },
                                        error       : function(){
                                            openAlert('No Connection','exitApp');

                                        },
                                        timeout     : 6000
                                    });  
                    });
                }else{
                    openAlert('Failed to send order');
                }
            },
            error       : function(){
                openAlert('No Connection','exitApp');
            },
            timeout     : 6000
        });
    }
});

function clear_interval_job()
{
    clearInterval(interval_job);
}
```